# Subform inside modal

Tags: joomla-3.x, development, plugin, modal, subform

I am using subform form field type inside my plugin parameters (I am reusing a form in several places of my plugin parameters, with success).

What I really need to manage is to use each subform inside a modal window. I need to shorten the parameters list, making it more user-friendly.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible out of the box.

Maybe you can create your own JFormField which creates wrapper around the subform.